# Understanding the differences between similar numpy flattening techniques

Tags: python, image, numpy, reshape

I'm working through the homework assignment for week 2 of the first course in the deeplearning.ai certificate on Coursera.

One of the first tasks is to flatten an image (209, 64, 64, 3). You can do this in three ways (or so I think):

1. X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1).T
2. X.flatten().reshape(12288, 209)
3. X.reshape(12288, 209)

In this exercise, I found that only option one properly reshapes the image but I have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1).T == X.reshape(-1, X.shape[0])` and here`X.flatten().reshape(12288, 209)` you flatten and then reshape into a non flat form, also in the last one. which of these produced the desired result?

Comment: Is that one image or 209 images? Only 1 respects the order of elements in the (64,64) blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we note that we can think of `reshape` as "pulling" an array out into a long line of elements, and then "restacking" them by filling axes in a certain order. Consider the following array:

```
array = np.arange(48).reshape(6, 4, 2)
```

This array will contain elements from 0 to 47 and have shape `(6, 4, 2)`. This shape can be interpreted simply as the *order in which elements were placed into each axis*.

For example:

```
>>> print(array[0, :, :])
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]]
```

The length of the first axis is `48 / 4 / 2 = 8`, and therefore this slice must have 8 elements. Since it is the *first* axis, it simply consists of the first 8 elements of the source in running order.

Next, we need to decide how these 8 elements will fill the other 2 axes. These 8 elements can be thought of as forming a sub-array of their own, with shape `(4, 2)`. Since the first axis (in the sub-array) must be filled up first, we would expect it to contain pairs of elements in running order:

```
>>> for i in range(array.shape[1]):
...    print(array[0, i, :])
[0 1]
[2 3]
[4 5]
[6 7]
```

Contrast this with the last axis:

```
>>> for i in range(array.shape[2]):
...     print(array[0, :, i])
[0 2 4 6]
[1 3 5 7]
```

The second slice, `array[1, :, :]`, will then contain the *next* 8 elements, or 8 to 15, with this process repeated until no more elements are left.

Now, note that the "pulling out" step is akin to `flatten()`. Therefore, it should come as no surprise that 2 and 3 **are the same**:

```
X = np.random.rand(209, 64, 64, 3)
print(X.flatten().reshape(12288, 209) == X.reshape(12288, 209)).all(axis=None)
```

Output:

```
True
```

A cursory comparison with 1. will reveal, therefore, that 1. is the odd one out. Note that `X.shape[0]` is equal to `209` (the length of `X`'s first axis). Therefore, 1. is equivalent to `X.reshape(209, -1).T` (-1 is shorthand for inferring the last axis, and `.T` transposes an array).

The two are therefore different not in their *shape*, but in the *order in which the elements were placed into the axes*. 2. and 3. started from the same point, a flattened array consisting of elements in the first row, then the second, then the third, and so on. Therefore, `(0, 0)` contains the first original element, and then `(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)`...

**On the other hand**, by performing the reshaping in 1. and *then* transposing, this linear order of elements is no longer respected. Instead, columns are filled first, such that `(0, 0)` contains the first original element, and then `(1, 0)`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The end result of all three operations will be the same. The three methods are just three different ways of achieving the same result. But there should be some catch, right? Yes, there is.

1. **X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1).T**: When you pass `-1` as an axis to the reshape operation, you are saying `Hey, here is my array. I am giving you the first dimension(X.shape[0] in this case), figure out yourself what the second dimesnion should be!`. Because `reshape` is just another way of arranging the elements, `numpy` will take all the other dimension that and take a product of the shapes for the second dimension.
2. **X.flatten().reshape(12288, 209)**: Here you are saying that `Yes, I know the shape of the ndarray I want` but instead of directly reshaping it, you first `flattened` it out and then rearranged the elements.
3. **X.reshape(12288, 209)**: This is same as the second option but know you are not doing a **`redundant`** `flatten` operation to reshape your ndarray.

What else?:  **Time taken**

```
a = np.random.rand(2,3,4) 
%timeit d = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
382 ns ± 8.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit b = a.flatten().reshape(2,12)
963 ns ± 11.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit c = a.reshape(2,12)
272 ns ± 4.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

print(b.shape, c.shape, d.shape)
(2, 12) (2, 12) (2, 12)

print((a.flatten()==b.flatten()).all())
True

print((a.flatten()==c.flatten()).all())
True

print((a.flatten()==d.flatten()).all())
True
```

Comment: This is wrong. You are calling `all` on each of the arrays, which will return `True` if all their elements are nonzero, and therefore you are printing the result of `(True == True == True == True)`. You want `(a == b).all() and (b == c).all() and (c == d).all()`.

Comment: Why did you flatten in the tests?  Why not use `np.allclose`?

Answer (score 0):

`(209, 64, 64, 3)` looks like the shape of an array of images, 209 images each (64,64,3).  Reshaping should keep those image elements together and in order.

Illustrating with a smaller example:

```
In [845]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,2,3)                                    
In [846]: arr                                                                   
Out[846]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]]])
In [847]: arr[1]                                                                
Out[847]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

The naive reshape:

```
In [848]: x = arr.reshape(6,4)                                                  
In [849]: x                                                                     
Out[849]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
In [850]: x[:,1]                                                                
Out[850]: array([ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21])
```

Selecting a column produces a different set of numbers than in `Out[847]`.  `[6,7,8]` now split between rows 2 and 3.  And the `[1,5,9...]` are drawn from all over `arr`.

Reshape followed by tranpose: (4,2,3)=>(4,(2*3))=>(4,6)=>(6,4):

```
In [851]: x = arr.reshape(4,6).T                                                
In [852]: x                                                                     
Out[852]: 
array([[ 0,  6, 12, 18],
       [ 1,  7, 13, 19],
       [ 2,  8, 14, 20],
       [ 3,  9, 15, 21],
       [ 4, 10, 16, 22],
       [ 5, 11, 17, 23]])
In [853]: x[:,1]                                                                
Out[853]: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [855]: x[:,1].reshape(2,3)                                                   
Out[855]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Formally `reshape` just requires that the total number of elements doesn't change.  But as illustrated here, subgroups of dimensions should also remain the same, `(4,2,3) => (4,6)` or `(8,3)`, not `(6,4)`.  Otherwise you risk regrouping values.

With just reshape and transpose, `x` is still a `view`, sharing the databuffer with `arr`.  But the `order` is different.  Further reshaping (e.g. `ravel`) is likely to produce a copy.

```
In [859]: arr.__array_interface__['data']                                       
Out[859]: (36072624, False)
In [860]: x.__array_interface__['data']                                         
Out[860]: (36072624, False)
In [861]: x.ravel()                                                             
Out[861]: 
array([ 0,  6, 12, 18,  1,  7,...])
In [862]: x.ravel(order='F')                                                    
Out[862]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, ...])
```